# User preferred language saved but the page content language didn't change only after I reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro, umijs

I'm using ant design pro.
The idea is In the platform we have 2 languages to choose from Fr(French) and En(English),
I want the user when he logs in and change the language to English for example when he logs out and log in again the language should be saved to English so he would be able to see the content in English, I managed to do it, when i login in the backend the preferedLanguage = en, the language toggle in the  also changes to en, the only problem the web page content stays in French it's only change in English when i reload the page.
I think the issue is related to the login page, the login page is set to French as default , let's say my preferred language now is English, if i login from the login page. The page content loaded in French only changes when i reload.

-This is the umijs documentation : https://umijs.org/docs/max/i18n#setlocale-%E8%AE%BE%E7%BD%AE%E8%AF%AD%E8%A8%80

-LanguageDropdown (the toggle where you select the language (Fr or En)

```
import type { FC } from 'react';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Menu, Dropdown } from 'antd';
import { CaretDownOutlined, CaretUpOutlined, GlobalOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import styles from './index.less';
import { setLocale, getLocale, getAllLocales } from 'umi';

interface Props {
  setUpdateLang: any;
  currentLang: string;
}

const LanguageDropdown: FC<Props> = ({ currentLang, setUpdateLang }) => {
  const [langvisible, setLangVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [localesList, setLocalesList] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [currentLocale, setCurrentLocale] = useState<string>('');

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (currentLang) {
  //     setLocalesList(getAllLocales());
  //     setCurrentLocale(getLocale());
  //     setLocale(currentLang === 'fr' ? 'fr-FR' : 'en-US');

  //   }
  //    alert(currentLang);
  //    alert(getLocale());
  // }, [currentLang]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalesList(getAllLocales());
    setCurrentLocale(getLocale());

    if (currentLang) {
      // alert(222);
      const selectedLang = currentLang === 'fr' ? 'fr-FR' : 'en-US';
      // setNewLang(selectedLang);
      setLocale(selectedLang, false);
      setCurrentLocale(getLocale());
    }
  }, [currentLang]);

  const onLangVisibleChange = (visibleLang: boolean) => {
    setLangVisible(visibleLang);
  };

  const langNameHandler = (lang: string) => {
    if (lang === 'en-US') return 'EN';
    else if (lang === 'fr-FR') return 'FR';
    return 'FR';
  };

  const setNewLang = (lang: string) => {
    setUpdateLang({ lang: langNameHandler(lang).toLocaleLowerCase(), updated: true });
    setLocale(lang);
  };

  const Langmenu = (
    <Menu>
      {localesList?.map((lang: any) => (
        <Menu.Item key={lang}>
          <a onClick={() => setNewLang(lang)}>{langNameHandler(lang)}</a>
        </Menu.Item>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <div className={styles.profileDropdownContainer}>
      <Dropdown
        overlay={Langmenu}
        placement="bottomLeft"
        trigger={['click']}
        onVisibleChange={onLangVisibleChange}
        className={styles.dropdown}
      >
        <div className={styles.langContainer}>
          <span>
            <GlobalOutlined /> {langNameHandler(currentLocale)}
          </span>
          {!langvisible ? <CaretDownOutlined /> : <CaretUpOutlined />}
        </div>
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LanguageDropdown;
```

-RightContext

```
import { Tag } from 'antd';
import type { Settings as ProSettings } from '@ant-design/pro-layout';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import type { ConnectProps } from 'umi';
import type { Dispatch } from 'umi';
import { connect } from 'umi';
import type { ConnectState } from '@/models/connect';
import Avatar from './AvatarDropdown';
import styles from './index.less';
import LanguageDropdown from '../languageDropdown';
import moment from 'moment';

export type GlobalHeaderRightProps = {
  dispatch: Dispatch;
  theme?: ProSettings['navTheme'] | 'realDark';
  auth: any;
  users: any;
  platformLanguage: any;
  data: any;
} & Partial<ConnectProps> &
  Partial<ProSettings>;

const ENVTagColor = {
  dev: 'orange',
  test: 'green',
  pre: '#87d068',
};

const GlobalHeaderRight: React.FC<GlobalHeaderRightProps> = (props) => {
  const [updateLang, setUpdateLang] = useState<{ lang: string; updated: boolean }>({
    lang: '',
    updated: false,
  });
  const [currentLang, setCurrentLang] = useState<any>(null);
  const { theme, layout, auth, platformLanguage, data, dispatch } = props;
  let className = styles.right;

  useEffect(() => setCurrentLang(platformLanguage), [platformLanguage]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (updateLang.updated) {
      const {
        organization,
        roles,
        email,
        deleted,
        department,
        createdById,
        organizationId,
        ...rest
      } = data;
      const birthdate = moment(rest.birthdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      const workversary = moment(rest.workversary).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      dispatch({
        type: 'users/updateMe',
        payload: {
          data: { ...rest, birthdate, workversary, platformLanguage: updateLang.lang },
          userId: auth?.currentUser.id,
        },
      });

      setUpdateLang({ ...updateLang, updated: false });
      setCurrentLang(updateLang.lang);
    }
  }, [updateLang]);

  if (theme === 'dark' && layout === 'top') {
    className = `${styles.right}  ${styles.dark}`;
  }

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {currentLang ? (
        <LanguageDropdown currentLang={currentLang} setUpdateLang={setUpdateLang} />
      ) : null}

      <Avatar />
      {REACT_APP_ENV && (
        <span>
          <Tag color={ENVTagColor[REACT_APP_ENV]}>{REACT_APP_ENV}</Tag>
        </span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(({ settings, auth, users }: ConnectState) => ({
  theme: settings.navTheme,
  layout: settings.layout,
  auth,
  users,
  platformLanguage: auth?.currentUser?.membership?.platformLanguage,
  data: auth?.currentUser?.membership,
}))(GlobalHeaderRight);
```

-LoginLayout

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import type { ConnectState } from '@/models/connect';
import type { MenuDataItem } from '@ant-design/pro-layout';
import { getMenuData, getPageTitle } from '@ant-design/pro-layout';
import { useIntl, connect } from 'umi';
import type { ConnectProps } from 'umi';
import { Col, Row } from 'antd';
import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import LoginImage from '../assets/loginImage.png';
import SignUpAdminImage from '../assets/adminSignup.svg';
import styles from './LoginLayout.less';
import LanguageDropdown from '@/components/languageDropdown';
import SignupSideText from '@/components/SignupSideText';

export type UserLayoutProps = {
  breadcrumbNameMap: Record<string, MenuDataItem>;
} & Partial<ConnectProps>;

const LoginLayout: React.FC<UserLayoutProps> = (props) => {
  const [layoutImage, setLayoutImage] = useState(LoginImage);
  const [updateLang, setUpdateLang] = useState<{ lang: string; updated: boolean }>({
    lang: '',
    updated: false,
  });
  const [currentLang, setCurrentLang] = useState<any>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (updateLang.updated) {
      setUpdateLang({ ...updateLang, updated: false });
      setCurrentLang(updateLang.lang);
    }
  }, [updateLang]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.pathname === '/user/adminSignup/step1') {
      setLayoutImage(SignUpAdminImage);
    } else if (window.location.pathname === '/user/adminSignup/step2') {
      setLayoutImage('TextSignup');
    } else setLayoutImage(LoginImage);
  }, [window.location.pathname]);
  const {
    route = {
      routes: [],
    },
  } = props;
  const { routes = [] } = route;
  const {
    children,
    location = {
      pathname: '',
    },
  } = props;
  const { formatMessage } = useIntl();
  const { breadcrumb } = getMenuData(routes);
  const title = getPageTitle({
    pathname: location.pathname,
    formatMessage,
    breadcrumb,
    ...props,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <HelmetProvider>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{title}</title>
          <meta name="description" content={title} />
        </Helmet>

        <div className={styles.container}>
          <Col
            xl={{ span: 12, order: 1 }}
            xs={{ span: 0, order: 2 }}
            md={{ span: 0, order: 2 }}
            lg={{ span: 0, order: 2 }}
            style={{ backgroundColor: '#00bfa5' }}
          >
            {layoutImage === 'TextSignup' ? (
              <SignupSideText />
            ) : (
              <img alt="logo" width="100%" height="100%" src={layoutImage} />
            )}
          </Col>
          <Col
            xl={{ span: 12, order: 2 }}
            lg={{ span: 24, order: 2 }}
            sm={{ span: 24, order: 1 }}
            xs={{ span: 24, order: 1 }}
          >
            {' '}
            <Row justify="end" className="languageRow">
              <LanguageDropdown currentLang={currentLang} setUpdateLang={setUpdateLang} />
            </Row>
            {children}
          </Col>
        </div>
      </HelmetProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default connect(({ settings }: ConnectState) => ({ ...settings }))(LoginLayout);
```